# Linked list of Linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I have a project in C that I need to create a chained hash table with linked lists.
Actually as I see it is a linked list with linked lists as nodes.
So the data structure of each node in each entry in hash table should be:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    int counter;
    struct node *next;
} t_listnode;
```

and then the hash table that should contain the above nodes is stated as below:

```
typedef struct {
    t_listnode *head;
    t_listnode *tail;
} t_htentry;
```

I have drained my little brain (first time touching linked lists) and can't figure how to create the hash table and how to enter data in each entry.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, because a linked list of linked lists and a hash table that uses linked lists are not at all the same thing. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is a *chained* hash table? The whole point in hash table is that you have an array and not a linked list. I agree that the array cells should point to linked list - so if there are multiple values that are mapped to the same cell, you can store all of them in the list. But the main data structure should be an array - so you can access the index in O(1). In linked list it is O(n) as you need to go over all the pointers

Comment: Lets say that I want to have the above combined linked list. To have a linked list t_htentry, which contain the t_listnode nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using an outer linked list and an inner linked list:

First, to make your life easier, you should make some methods for your inner linked list `node`:

- `insert()`: Iterate to the end of the linked list and add a new node
- `find()`: Iterate through the list and see if your value is what you're looking for

Next, you'll want to implement the relevant methods for a Hash Table:

- `get()` or `find()`: hash the element you're looking for to get the index in the outer linked list, and then iterate through the inner linked list at that index to find the element you're looking for
- `put()` or `insert()`: hash the element you're looking for to get the index in the outer linked list, where you'll append to the end of the inner linked list at that index

Most importantly for a hash table, you'll want to create your `hash()` function. In this case, since your data appears to be an `int`, your hash function should take in an int and then hash that int to a given spot in the outer linked list.

Since you're using a linked list to represent the outer structure of the hash table, you will definitely want to create an `at()` method that iterates through the outer linked-list (`t_htentry`) and returns a pointer to the index of the inner linked list (in your case, a `t_listnode` node).

**Example**:

We want to add 10, 201, 302 into our hash table.

First step is to pre-allocate the `t_htentry* hashtable[PRIME_NUMBER]` to a prime size -- i.e., let's say we start with an array of size 5 (each index in the array is denoted by `[ ]`). The `t_listnode* head` is already in each of the `t_htentry*`'s, (each `t_htentry*` is denoted by `( )`, the head nodes are denoted by `*`, and the tail nodes are denoted by `t`).

```
  0      1      2      3      4  -- indexes
[(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)] -- t_htentry*[] with t_listnode* head in each index
  |      |      |      |      |
  v      v      v      v      v  -- pointer
 (t)    (t)    (t)    (t)    (t) -- t_listnode* tail
```

Second step is to hash our first data point - 10.

```
int idx = hash(10); //-> 2
```

Third step is to locate `idx` (2) in our outer list. `hashtable[idx]` will give us a constant time lookup!

Fourth step is to now append a node with the data point 5 to that list.

```
// append value to hashtable[idx] (where "next" points to TAIL)
insert(hashtable[idx], 5);

[(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]
  |      |      |      |      |
  |      |      v      |      |
  |      |     (5)     |      |
  |      |      |      |      |
  v      v      v      v      v
 (t)    (t)    (t)    (t)    (t)
```

Fifth step, we now proceed to our next data point, 201. Let's say 201 hashes to `idx = 2` as well. (From this point on, I'm omitting drawing the `[(t)]`'s for all indices that don't have any data in them, but note that they are still there.)

```
idx = hash(201); //-> 2
t_listnode * spot = positionAt(hashtable, idx);
insert(spot, 201);

[(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]
                |
                v
               (5)
                |
                v
               (2)
                |
                v
               (t)
```

Next step, we'll move to our last data point, 302. Let's say 302 hashes to `idx = 0`.

```
 idx = hash(302); //-> 0
 t_listnode * spot = positionAt(hashtable, idx);
 insert(spot, 302);

 [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]  [(*)]
   |             |
   v             v
 (302)          (5)
   |             |
   v             v
  (t)           (2)
                 |
                 v
                (t)
```

where,

`hash` would look like one of [these examples](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs070.200101/homework10/hashfuncs.html)

`insert` looks like

```
void insert(t_htentry * bucket, int value) {
  // copy spot to a new t_listnode* and iterate until spot->next is NULL
  // (i.e., t_htentry* tmp = bucket; tmp = bucket->head->next)
  // create a new node with t_listnode->value set to value
  // set the current spot's next to the new node
  // set the new node's next to the TAIL node
}
```

`find` looks like

```
bool find(hashtable, int value) {
  // hash "value" and go to hashtable[idx] as before
  // iterate through hashtable[idx]'s linked list as before using a copy
  // of that t_htentry*.
  // if the node that you're on has ->value == value, return true
  // else continue until you're at the end of the list, and return false
}
```

The performance for this implementation will be O(1) amortized for `find` and `insert`. It's important that you understand why.

Comment: I'm fairly certain he doesn't need a 30,000 ft. overview of what list/hash functions do. Perhaps an example illustrating your approach is in order.

Comment: Sounds good. Unsure how detailed to get given this is a project.

Comment: @Michael Recachinas: I have all those functions that you describe. In order to start I need to understand (an example would be great) how to enter nodes on the t_htentry list.

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas generally a short 2-3 node dataset read into the list, iterated to find/print a node given some hash key. Just so he sees how the pieces are sewn together.

Comment: @ToroLoco let me know if the example is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you for the example code. I am totally confused :(, I am reading again the exercise and can't understand if the t_htentry is an array. Since I am greek I can't transfer it exactly.

Comment: @ToroLoco: No problem. Definitely ask questions so we can help you be less confused! :) The only difference between an outer linked-list and an array implementation is with an array, you don't need to iterate through the array to get to the inner linked list, you simply do `arr[idx]`, and that should give you the t_listnode*.

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas: but why I declare the t_htentry with t_listnode *head and *tail? where should I use those? and the array will be a t_listnode[SIZE] array or as I understand a t_htentry[SIZE]?

Comment: @ToroLoco: It will be an array of `t_htentry*`, so `t_htentry* hashtable[SIZE]`. So, I will edit my example, but effectively, the "dummy head" I refer to in my example is the `t_listnode* head` in `t_htentry`.

Comment: For the detail and effort you put into this answer, +1. (I happen to _like_ the view at 30,000 ft.

Comment: @ryyker thanks :) I hope I've been able to answer ToroLoco's questions in hopes of alleviating the confusion.